# Easiest way to publish angular 2 app to Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, angular

I have an initial version of my website completed using **angular-cli v1.0.0-beta.18**, **angular v2.1.1**, **angular-material v2.0.0-alpha.9-3** and **Promact/md2 v0.0.6** (for **select** and **datepicker** components since these are not ready yet in material 2).

I have also signed up for 1 year free trial with **Amazon AWS**.

So my question is, what is the simplest way to build and deploy my application to **AWS**?

My application is currently self-contained but I will be creating a Java micro-service next that my application will need to use over **REST** - but that is a couple of months away from completion.

Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use S3 static websites feature.  Its great for front end apps.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

If you want to get really fancy then you can take it a step further and layer in AWS Cloud Front.  But I wouldn't do that until you are in production and are concerned about first page loading time.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Just to clarify, I would build my app using **ng build --prod** and then deploy the files in the **dist** folder onto **AWS**?

Comment: Correct.  Its might even be worth setting up a Continuous Build/Deploy service to do that part for you.

Comment: Many thanks again. I would really appreciate it if you had any links to how to setup Continuous Build/Deploy services.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_continuous_integration_software

Comment: I am a fan of CircleCI. I have used BambooCI as well, its pretty good.

Comment: I have my code checked into BitBucket as a private repo - would that influence my choice of Continuous Build/Deploy services?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126446/discussion-between-george-m-whitaker-and-mufasa).

Comment: The problem is that the components URLs are not directly accessible, have to use the s3 redirect hack but it means returning 404 for all pages :s

Comment: The router module doesn't seem to work on AWS S3. S3 treats URL like a path to a static file and didn't even invoke Angular's client-side render. As a result refresh and back/forward button does not work on S3. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not tied to AWS and your end goal is just to be in cloud, there are several options. There is one service that I wrote you can try - called [Plugins by Quadnix](https://plugins.quadnix.com/home).

This is an automatic platform which guesses the infrastructure rather than being told what to build. E.g. you mentioned you are building a Java application in comments. Rather than configuring different components like tomcat, database, loggers, etc, these infrastructure can be automatically detected and build by my service. What's more is that it has an embedded CICD pipeline, and many other features.
Most of these features e.g. database support is yet to be built, but the **"Angular"** piece is working correctly. You can follow this [video link](https://www.youtube.com/embed/-8jaCIbZ2Is) to get started.